# Spring cloud config in local dev mode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to control if the application requires spring-config-server based on profile.

I want to pick properties from resource/... in say local-dev profile and use cloud-config only with a profile where there would be a config-server running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable using config-server for a specific profile. Please try to define the properties in `bootstrap.yml` like below. Please note, we should configure these settings only in `bootstrap.yml`. Setting these properties in `application.yml` will not work. In this case, `local` profile will be running only with local profiles in /resources folder. In `dev` profile, properties from config-server will override properties from resources/ folder.

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://<your config server>
```